# horizontal inline alignment

Tags: css, html, alignment

I assigned a h2 and p element within a section id named mission. You can check the detailed code here http://jsfiddle.net/5Umm3/
I constantly face problem to align two elements in horizontally direction. Rather they start aligning vertically, the height is 45 px and I wanted h2 element i.e. mission to be vertically center aligned in 45 px height of the section id mission and the p id also to vertically center align in 45 px height. h2 and p being horizontally aligned inline to each other. Also I see the p to have somewhat bold type without me giving it bold, does it inherits the font weight from the previous id in this scenario? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

1. make the `h2` and the `p` in the `#mission` sit side by side.
2. remove the `bold` on the `p`.

To do that, I added `display:inline-block;` to both the `h2` and the `p`.

The `h2` was also vertically aligned to the top.  `Width` was added to both.

And I removed the `bold` with `font-weight:normal;`.

```
#mission h2{
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:40px;
    color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#mission p{
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-right:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:450px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/5Umm3/2/

Answer (score 0):

I honeztly tried to understand what your question was, but I just can't follow most of it.  Try using short sentences with a clear question that end in a question mark to ask a question.

The only sentence that ends in a question mark is asking with the p has bold.  If you look at your HTML in any reasonable debugger (like Firebug or Chrome debugger), you can see that the p gets bold because of this CSS:

```
#mission {font-weight: bold;}
```

Since the p tag is contained inside the mission section, it is covered by any settings on the mission section unless you override the p formatting more locally.  If you wanted to control the p separately, you could use CSS like this:

```
#mission p {font-weight: normal;}
```

As for all that you wrote about alignment, I don't follow what your question is.  Please rephrase a simple question and we can try to help.

**Edit:**
Still guessing what you want here, but if you want the left edge of the "Mission" title to line up with the left edge of the text below it, then remove the indicated line in this part of your CSS:

```
#mission h2{
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:40px;    // <---- Remove this line
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Well, I want to see how I can have p and h2 horizontally aligned to each other instead of vertically alignment which they have right now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand.  I see the title "Mission" and I see a paragraph of text following it that starts out "We strive to provide...".  Do you just want Mission moved left so the left edge of it aligns with the text?  If so, see the first edit in my answer above for how to do that.